# Testing a @yield value

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-5.6

I want to add a class to one of my components in my main template, but only on a specific page.

Is there a way to test the @yield's value ?

So far, I tested this but it didn't work (*ie* the class is added whenever the pagename is set, regardless of its content) :

```
<div class="
    @hasSection('pagename') && @yield('pagename') == 'home'
        myclass
    @endif
">
```

Comment: Perhaps use "stack" instead?

Comment: Kind of hacky, but it works !

Comment: Not hacky :), I use it all the time to insert JavaScript when its actually needed. Is that hacky?

Comment: I also use it to add CSS and JS files when needed, but I never used it as a classname loader ;)

Comment: Oh, I see, yea that seems to be hacky :D, I just read *I want to use yield sometimes*, and right away - stack is the way to go here. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a combination of the `@if` directive and `request()` helper. Something along the lines of:

```
@if(request()->routeIs('some-named-route')) {{ echo 'my-class' }} @endif
```

[Extending blade](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/blade#custom-if-statements) would provide a reusable directive:

```
// AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot()
{
    Blade::if('custom', function ($route) {
        return request()->routeIs(route);
    });
}

// view.blade.php
@custom('some-route')
    'my-class'
@endcustom
```